# How does one grab the CPU temp of a raspberry pi 4 running android 13 using a kotlin android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, raspberry-pi, arm, lineageos

I have a pretty niche question. The question is how do you grab the CPU temperature programmatically from the raspberry pi 4 that is running the LineageOS 20 build of Android 13 and assign it to a var? Below I have included the code that I have been using and not succeeding with:

```
fun cpuTemperature(): Float {
    val process: Process
    return try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
        process.waitFor()
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
        val line: String = reader.readLine()
        if (line != null) {
            val temp = line.toFloat()
            temp / 1000.0f
        } else {
            51.0f
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        0.0f
    }
}
```

I understand this a bit of a weird question and most people probably wont have experience doing something like this so I appreciate any help or insight into how garbing CPU temp on android apps works.

Comment: Try a `/` before `sys`: `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`. I don't know whether you can access `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` from an ordinary Android app without root, but without the leading `/`, you're doomed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I gave that a try and it didn't help but I appreciate the suggestion